# Apify array results displayed in one row instead of separate rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, apify

I'm testing Apify web scraper and i am able to see the results but it's displayed in one row. I'm iterating contents to grab titles from this page - ... and pushing it to array and finally returning array. I would like to see the titles returned in separate rows. Would really appreciate if someone could point me to right direction.

Here is my page function:

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
    // jQuery is handy for finding DOM elements and extracting data from them.
    // To use it, make sure to enable the "Inject jQuery" option.
    const $ = context.jQuery;
    var results = [];
    $('.ms-srch-group-content').each(function(){
        results.push({
            title: $(this).find('.ms-srch-item-link').text().trim(),
            date: $(this).find('.soi-news-attributes').text().trim(),
        });
    });
    return results;
}
```

Here is the result:
...

As you can see in the result screenshot, all the titles are displayed in one row.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're trying to iterate over the element itself, while what you're trying to achieve would require to move down by one level.

That said - you would only need to change `.ms-srch-group-content` to `.ms-srch-group-content > div[name=Item]` and it would work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like .ms-srch-group-content is selector for group content, so you receive one record not an array.
I guess you need to move down to the next div - .ms-srch-item

```
$('.ms-srch-item').each(function(){
```